# Не получается импортировать модули в pygame/tkinter PyCharm (LinuxManjaro)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pygame, manjaro

В PyCharm при попытке импорта модулей, pygame/tkinter ошибки см-ниже
При попытке установить через File-Setings-PythonInterpreter-Install Ошибка:

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python3.8'.

        Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/pycharm/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
        runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
        return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
        _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
        sys.exit(_main())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
        command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
        module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
        from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 16, in <module>
        from pip._internal.distributions import (
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
    ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/__init__.py)
```

Использовал: `pip3 install pygame` результат:

```
    [r00t@Extensa ~]$ pip3 install pygame
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2 MB 529 kB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-avkbxiph/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-avkbxiph/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-kvux4cab
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-avkbxiph/pygame/
    Complete output (18 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTTIME: not found
    FREETYPE: found 23.2.17
    Missing dependencies
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: sudo pamac install python-pygame, https://pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted раздел Arch/Manjaro.?

Comment: Manjaro, код выше помог только с pygame спасибо.
Tkinter все также выдает ошибку в py charm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r00t/Документы/pythonProject/my_Project/testing.py", line 4, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505199/12785139 ?

Comment: Это помогло спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted): `sudo pamac install python-pygame`

`sudo pacman -S tk` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48505199/12785139)

Comment: Да именно эта команда мне помогла подключить pygame, спасибо